# Static array allocation

Tags: c, memory, static, allocation

I have this implementation of alloc, which allocates memory as a dynamic array.

My question is that what does it mean that the array and pointer are declared static? How does it affect to a function that calls alloc?

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000 /* size of available space */

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];   /* storage for alloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf;    /* next free position */

char *alloc(int n)   /* return pointer to n characters */
{

    if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) {  /* it fits */
        allocp += n;
        return allocp - n; /* old p */
    }  else               /* not enough room */
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I have this implementation of alloc, which allocates memory as a dynamic array". There doesn't appear to be be any dynamic arrays in your code.

Comment: @AlanAu define *dynamic*

Comment: You should not use `0` as null pointer constant. Instead use the `NULL` macro. Note that even C++ learned this lesson, favouring `nullptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is that what does it mean that the array and pointer are declared static?

It means the lifetime of the arrays is the entire execution of the program. Any object defined at file-scope (with or without the `static` specifier) has static storage duration (exception: objects defined with C11 `_Thread_local` specifier). Adding the `static` specifier limits the visibility of the objects to the source file they are defined.

The total size of your `alloc` allocations is limited by the size of your `allocbuf` array.

Comment: So adding the static specifier only limits the visibility of the objects to the source file?

Comment: @user004325 yes, for objects defined at file-scope, adding `static` (versus no storage specifier) makes the objects private to the translation unit.

Comment: What does this mean in practice?

Comment: @user004325 that you cannot access `allocbuf` array directly from another source file, which is the purpose of adding `static` here. `allocbuf` presence is an implementation detail that is hidden for the `alloc` user.

Comment: Does alloc do dynamic memory allocation?